# javascript hide dropdown when click anywhere

Tags: javascript, tooltip

Hello I want to hide droppdown tool tip when I click on out side that div, below is my code

```
// tooltip function

function ddtoolTip(){

  document.getElementById("ddtoolTip").style.visibility='visible';

};

function removeToolTip(){

  document.getElementById("cancel").style.visibility='hide';    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
document.getElementById("cancel").style.visibility='hidden';
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("cancel").style.visibility='hide';
```

you can refer to [CSS Visibility Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Comment: The solution is correct but please stop using W3schools as reference if you want to take programming seriously. Instead use official sites like http://www.w3.org/ & http://www.ecma-international.org/

Answer (score 0):

**Hide text with display property**

```
document.getElementById("cancel").style.display="none";
```

**Hide text with visibility property**

```
document.getElementById("cancel").style.visibility="hidden";
```